# how can we get session of particular promotion rule using model

Tags: magento

**Is there any way to get session of salesrule using model?** I have to get details of rule while it is being created.. for eg: i have to get **apply_to_shipping** and **coupon_type** while rule is being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add observer to `salesrule_rule_save_before` event. In your observer use `$observer->getEvent()->getRule()` to get sales rule object.

Comment: Thanks, As I am amateur in php and magento could you please provide me how can I define it as well as get apply_to_shipping and coupon_type using it

Comment: I guess this [article](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) will help you.

Comment: Thanks Zyava, That article surely helped me. But I found something else, I think you may know it. By using <pre>Mage::Registry('current_promo_rule')->getRuleId();<code>, we can access everything.